# The meaning of いた in this sentence related to be left surviving

Tags: verbs

The whole sentence is:

> だが、偶然にも生き残ったサイア人たちがいた。

Could it be:

> However, fortuitously surviving sayajins remained.

In this case, this いた is the past of 居る? If this right, 居る could have the reading "to remain" or "the be left" in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: いる doesn't mean "to remain" or "to leave". It just means "to be" or "there is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いた just means "there was ～" here. いた is the past tense of いる ("to be", "to exist"). And is サイア人 a typo for サイ**ヤ**人?

> 生き残ったサイヤ人
>   Saiyans who survived
>
> 偶然にも生き残ったサイヤ人
>   Saiyans who happened to survive
>
> だが、偶然にも生き残ったサイヤ人たち**がいた**。
>   However, **there were** Saiyans who happened to survive.

Answer (score 1):

As youy say, `いた` is the past of `居る`.